# ZF3 Upgrade unable to render Template

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm upgrading from ZF2 to ZF3 and this goes quite well so far except the following issue when I want to load my application:

```
ERROR Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file

#0 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render()
#1 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(236): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(200): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(123): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(367): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /home/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(326): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /home/myproject/public/index.php(52): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

I thought the issue was I didn't had Zend\View loaded in my modules but it did load using composer autoload, when I add it again to my modules I get that it cannot be initilized, this might be because it already has.

Back to my issue, getConfig() is changed like described here:

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/migration/to-v3/application/

As I have ofcourse looked around and even the only topic here didn't help me so far.

Comment: Have you checked config files with view_manager configs? There should be an entry for 'error', which points to the actual error template file. Maybe the skeleton application is helpful to look up this config?

Comment: I had something todo with my autoload, it's fixed! thanks.